# How to load complex data using Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `CSV dataset` that looks like the below:

[image]

Also, PFB data in form of text:

```
Timestamp,How old are you?,What industry do you work in?,Job title,What is your annual salary?,Please indicate the currency,Where are you located? (City/state/country),How many years of post-college professional work experience do you have?,"If your job title needs additional context, please clarify here:","If ""Other,"" please indicate the currency here: "
4/24/2019 11:43:21,35-44,Government,Talent Management Asst. Director,75000,USD,"Nashville, TN",11 - 20 years,,
4/24/2019 11:43:26,25-34,Environmental nonprofit,Operations Director,"65,000",USD,"Madison, Wi",8 - 10 years,,
4/24/2019 11:43:27,18-24,Market Research,Market Research Assistant,"36,330",USD,"Las Vegas, NV",2 - 4 years,,
4/24/2019 11:43:27,25-34,Biotechnology,Senior Scientist,34600,GBP,"Cardiff, UK",5-7 years,,
4/24/2019 11:43:29,25-34,Healthcare,Social worker (embedded in primary care),55000,USD,"Southeast Michigan, USA",5-7 years,,
4/24/2019 11:43:29,25-34,Information Management,Associate Consultant,"45,000",USD,"Seattle, WA",8 - 10 years,,
4/24/2019 11:43:30,25-34,Nonprofit ,Development Manager ,"51,000",USD,"Dallas, Texas, United States",2 - 4 years,"I manage our fundraising department, primarily overseeing our direct mail, planned giving, and grant writing programs. ",
4/24/2019 11:43:30,25-34,Higher Education,Student Records Coordinator,"54,371",USD,Philadelphia,8 - 10 years,equivalent to Assistant Registrar,  
4/25/2019 8:35:51,25-34,Marketing,Associate Product Manager,"43,000",USD,"Cincinnati, OH, USA",5-7 years,"I started as the Marketing Coordinator, and was given the ""Associate Product Manager"" title as a promotion. My duties remained mostly the same and include graphic design work, marketing, and product management.",
```

Now, I tried the below code to load the data:

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("multiline", "true").option(
    "delimiter", ",").csv("path")
```

It gives me the output as below for the last record which divides the columns and also the output is not as expected:

[image]

The value should be **null** for the last column i.e `"If ""Other,"" please indicate the currency here: "` and the entire string should be wrapped up in the earlier column which is `"If your job title needs additional context, please clarify here:"`

I also tried `.option('quote','/"').option('escape','/"')` but didn't work too.

However, when I tried to load this file using `Pandas`, it was loaded correctly. I was surprised how `Pandas` can identify where the new column name starts and all. Maybe I can define a `String schema` for all the columns and load it back to the spark data frame but since I am using the lower spark version it won't work in a distributed manner hence I was exploring a way how Spark can handle this efficiently.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is consecutive double quotes in your csv file.
you have to escape extra double quotes in your csv file
Like this :

```
4/24/2019 11:43:30,25-34,Higher Education,Student Records Coordinator,"54,371",USD,Philadelphia,8 - 10 years,equivalent to Assistant Registrar,  
4/25/2019 8:35:51,25-34,Marketing,Associate Product Manager,"43,000",USD,"Cincinnati, OH, USA",5-7 years,"I started as the Marketing Coordinator, and was given the  \\" \ " Associate Product Manager \\" \ " title as a promotion. My duties remained mostly the same and include graphic design work, marketing, and product management.",
```

After this it is generating result as expected :

```
df2 = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("sample1.csv")

df2.show(10,truncate=False)
```

********  Output ********

```
|4/25/2019 8:35:51 |25-34           |Marketing                    |Associate Product Manager               |43,000                     |USD                         |Cincinnati, OH, USA                        |5-7 years                                                               |I started as the Marketing Coordinator, and was given the ""Associate Product Manager"" title as a promotion. My duties remained mostly the same and include graphic design work, marketing, and product management.|null       |null                                   |
```

Or you can use blow code

```
df2 = spark.read.option("header",True).option("multiline","true").option("escape","\"").csv("sample1.csv")
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer. It just that I had to add the additional property of `multiline` so that it would read the multiline values.